# What is isotropy actually & how does it ensure that exactly same number of molecules will move in either sides?

Tags: kinetic-theory

> Kinetic theory is also an example
>   of isotropy. It is assumed that the
>   molecules move in random
>   directions and as a consequence,
>   there is an equal probability of a
>   molecule moving in any direction.
>   Thus when there are many
>   molecules in the gas, with high
>   probability there will be very
>   similar numbers moving in one
>   direction as any other hence
>   demonstrating approximate
>   isotropy.

This is what [wikipedia](http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Isotropy) says. Now,what is isotropy actually? How does it ensure that exactly same number of molecules will move in the left and as well as in the right??

Isotropy,according to Wiki, is uniformity in all directions. So,is it saying,for exactly one molecule moving in the left,there must be one molecule moving in the right? Then what will happen if there is only one molecule? They have emphasized on **large number of molecules**. Now, why did they do so?

Is isotropy actually talking of equilibrium? Confused. Please help.

Comment: Isotropy refers to the behavior of some physical quantity with respect to a rotation in space. If some physical quantity is the same in any direction, we say that is isotropic. Isotropy is not only a propriety of a gas at thermodynamic equilibrium and in absence of fields. Isotropy is also a property of the space, of some media, and others. Isotropy in a state of a gas, is a statistical property, and good statistics you can do only for a large number of items. By the way, if the gas is not at equilibrium, the distribution of the velocities may be non-isotropic.

Comment: This is a comment on statistical behavior , and estimates probabilities of motion of a large number of particles. Isotropy means that the probability of moving in one direction is the same as in any other, and this behavior is implemented in the mathematical models of statistical mechanics to show how thermodynamic quantities, like temperature and entropy,  emerge from the aggregate of molecules.

Comment: Also, laws of nature do not prefer one direction over the other.